# Thermal Printing in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem in thermal printer. every time I print, there's some code/text that would be added like this.

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 17 19 595 773 
%%Pages: 1
..... 
%%BegingFeature: *InputSlot Upper 
2 dict up /PageSize [612 792] put dup /ImagingBox null put setpagedevice 
%%EndFeature 
.... 
%%EndSetup 
%%Page: 1 1 
%%BeginPageSetup 
%%EndPageSetup 
%%BeginDocument: nondsc 
Hello World 
%%EndDocument 
%%EOF
```

I just wanted to print the "Hello World", how will I eliminate the unwanted text in the output? is there something in my code?

My printer is ESC/POS 
Model P06-P 
My platform: Mac OS 10.8.2

my code is

```
String defaultPrinter = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName();
        System.out.println("Default printer: " + defaultPrinter);
        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        // prints the famous hello world! plus a form feed
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("hello world!\f".getBytes("UTF8"));

        PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        pras.add(new Copies(1));

        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

        job.print(doc, pras);
        is.close();
```

any help would be much appreciated

=======================================

When I try to print it on the CLI it prints, but when I made this code in java, it didn't print. waitFor() always return 1. I am sure the file is there, and the directory it is executing. But when I only issue "ls" it will have an output.

```
 List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
    cmd.add("lpr");
    cmd.add("-P");
    cmd.add("Prolific_Technology_Inc__IEEE_1284_Controller");
    cmd.add("-oraw");
    cmd.add("lalala.txt");

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    pb.directory(new File("src/org/cups4j/test"));
    Process p = pb.start();
    int res = p.waitFor();
    String line = null;
    try { 
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
        while( (line = input.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
     } catch (IOException e1) { 
         e1.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(0); 
     }    
    System.out.println("Result: " + res);
```

Comment: You should google for "java pos printing". What you see is the Postscript output, but you will need raw ascii output.

Comment: hi @PeterMmm, I google'd it but failed to find one.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBIZ/how-to-setup-the-epson-javapos-.html ---
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaPOS

Comment: hi @PeterMmm, I failed to get it to work.

I tried this in the console
"lpr -P "Prolific_Technology_Inc__IEEE_1284_Controller_2" -oraw lalala.txt"

it prints successfully. but when I tried the code above it has some headers added to it.

Comment: You may try to write output to a temp file and then run "lp" from Java with Runtime#exec().

Comment: Hi @PeterMmm I edited above, and decided to try the Runtime#exec() and ProcessBuilder but it didn't print.

Comment: 2 hints to avoid confusion: 1. Use an absolute path for working folder (/tmp); 2. put the absolute path to the print program /bin/lpr and check if it exists really (could be /bin/lp as well).

Comment: That prints the file. I wonder, why it didn't print in the directory that I am pointing last time. But when I point it to /tmp and made the file there. it prints. Thanks @PeterMmm.

Comment: I wonder why I always unplugged the usb cord of the printer to print again. It only prints once and I will have to unplug and reconnect the  cord again to print.

Comment: Propably you need to send a "reset" escape sequence at end of your file.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to do that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find the correct escape sequences in the (programer's) manual of the printer.

```
// ouput an escape sequence
byte ESC = 0x1b;
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("lalala.txt");
byte[] buf = new byte[]{ESC,0x31};
out.write(buf);
out.close();
```